# Elasticsearch 2+ JAVA API orFilter

Tags: java, elasticsearch, filtering

I am trying to write some Java code to query an ES5 instance. In ES1, you could OR and AND filters, orFilter and andFilter. What is the equivalent in ES5? I have tried -

```
QueryBuilder fb1 = QueryBuilders.termQuery("term1", "value1");
QueryBuilder fb2 = QueryBuilders.termQuery("term1", "value2");
QueryBuilder fb3 = QueryBuilders.termQuery("term2", "value3");

QueryBuilder fb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                        .must(fb1)
                        .should(fb2)

This gives results that match fb1, so this is not an OR

QueryBuilder fb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                        .must(fb1)
                        .must(fb2)

This gives no results, so the AND worked.
```

I want to figure out ways of constructing AND, OR queries

Answer (score 2):

In order to make an AND query, put all the conditions into "must".

```java
QueryBuilder fb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(fb1).must(fb2);
```

In order to make an OR query, put all the conditions into "should".

```java
QueryBuilder fb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(fb1).should(fb2);
```

Answer (score 0):

From ElasticSearch documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-compound-queries.html):

```
QueryBuilder qb = boolQuery()
    .must(termQuery("content", "test1"))    
    .must(termQuery("content", "test4"))    
    .mustNot(termQuery("content", "test2")) 
    .should(termQuery("content", "test3"))  
    .filter(termQuery("content", "test5"));
```

must seems like it might be the equivalent of the AND and should like it's the equivalent of the OR.

Comment: What doesn't work?  Can you post what you are trying?

Comment: QueryBuilder fb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                        .should(fb1)
                        .should(fb2)
to get the or

Answer (score 0):

You can use BoolQueryBuiler for these filters :

BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("customerId", customerId))

boolQueryBuilder.mustNot(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("reason", "failed"));

```
                    boolQueryBuilder.should(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("action", "deny")).minimumNumberShouldMatch(1);
```

QueryBuilder queryBuilder=boolQueryBuilder;

new SearchContext().prepareSearch(sc.getIndexNames()).setTypes(sc.getTypeName()).setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH).setQuery(queryBuilder);

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the above. How are you achieving an OR query?

Comment: Using minimumNumberShouldMatch(1) --> you can add multiple should filters and if you setminimumNumberShouldMatch as one ,it will at least try to match one of those filters .